# asp.net core can not rethrow async exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, exception, async-await

I`m having an issue with rethrowing exception in asp.net core.

Tested under .net core 2.1.402

```
    [HttpPost("processmessage")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Process(JObject obj, CancellationToken token)
    {
        var t = Task.Run(() => { return Task.FromException(new Exception("ab")); });

        try
        {
            await t;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
            var x = 0;
        }
        return Ok();
    }
```

Expected result: exception should be re-thrown and processed by asp.net core exception filter\middleware etc.

Current result: i can catch exception inside catch closure, but an exception is not re-thrown on asp.net level. The request is stuck (in postmen) for few minutes.

I also tried :

```
    [HttpPost("processmessage")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Process(JObject obj, CancellationToken token)
    {
        var t = Task.Run(() => { throw new Exception("ab"); });

        try
        {
            await t;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
        return Ok();
    }
```

And this code has completely the same behaviour as previous.

The only working solution for me is :

```
    [HttpPost("processmessage")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Process(JObject obj, CancellationToken token)
    {
        var t = Task.Run(() => { throw new Exception("ab"); });

        try
        {
            t.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
        return Ok();
    }
```

Can anybody explain why I can not re-throw exception in the first two scenarios? Is this behaviour expected or is it a bug in asp.net?

=== Update 10.18

**Example**: https://github.com/skynet2/net-core-debugger-issue/blob/master/WebApplication2/Controllers/ValuesController.cs

After some additional research, I was able to find the reason for such strange behaviour. In my case, the problem is inside DataServerExceptionFilter and the cause is **Debugger.Break()**;

I put a breakpoint on each line in exception filter and the strange point is that breakpoint **before Debugger.Break works** but after Dubbuger.Break the whole **processing is stopped**. and this doesn't work for async but works for .Wait()

Comment: Just tried to reproduce under net.framework 4.7.2 and it works without any issues.

Comment: What framework were you using before?

Comment: @PauloMorgado 2.1.402

Comment: Is there any project to reproduce your issue? I made a test with a new mvc template with `netcoreapp2.1` and fail to reproduce your issue. My .net core version is `2.1.403`.

Comment: It is very unlikely that your exception is not rethrown. Much more likely that it is not handled properly by asp.net for some reason. The main difference between your example is in the working one you're never yielding, so you're throwing the exception directly in the thread of the caller (whereas in other versions you've awaited the async call). It makes me think that whatever is calling you doesn't support properly async calls. Could you give the full callstack of your Process method? (disable "Just my code" in the VS options, set a breakpoint in your method and look at the callstack panel)

Comment: hi @KevinGosse just updated with an example and some explanation. In my case, the problem is async & Debugger.Break();

Comment: `Debugger.Break()` **is** a breakpoint. Just a programmatic one. When you reach that line, if a debugger is attached (like Visual Studio), it will automatically break. When that happens, just press F5 to resume execution

Comment: hi @KevinGosse i know what is Debugger.Break() but it does not break. The app just stuck. Also, it happens if you`ll run it under Release configuration. You can check out my sample.

Comment: Works perfectly for me. In debug and in release. It breaks on `Debugger.Break`, I resume execution, the page finishes loading